# How to monitor an Alternator exciter wire with MCU?

Tags: microcontroller, level-shifting, alternator

I have a internally regulated vehicle alternator which uses a conventional battery light wired in-between the exciter terminal and positive.

Obviously when the alternator isn't turning the exciter terminal is ground so the bulb is on, when the alternator is turning and charging the terminal becomes live thus no voltage difference and the bulb goes out.

I want to get rid of the bulb and have everything on my engine controlled and monitored with my own MCU.

As the alternator needs to 'see' a current on the exciter terminal I have no option but to replace the bulb with a low value resistor. Nothing above 25Ω works so I'm using a 20Ω resistor. This works and allows the alternator to charge.

I now want to hook up a 3v3 MCU to monitor the state of this circuit and to replace the visual element of the bulb. But it doesn't seem to be as simple as it first seems.

This is a standard alternator circuit:
[image]

This is the circuit I've tried:
[image]

This allows the alternator to charge and outputs 2.8-3v to the MCU when the alternator is charging, but when is 0.7V when not charging. Obviously I can get the voltage a bit higher by using a 3.3v zener ( I only had a 3v to hand), but how can I get the 0.7 lower. Ive tried putting a pull down resistor in parallel with the zener creating a voltage divider but this affects the 3v when the alternator is charging.

I've also tried using a onto coupler but no matter what value of resistor I use I cannot get the opto to trigger.

It may seem that 0.7 is low enough to register low but I want to make sure that this circuit will work with all alternators. So I need the value to be as low as possible.

What is the best way to monitor the exciter terminal of a alternator with a MCU?

Comment: One easy way to do it would be to keep the bulb and use a hall effect current sensor like https://www.allegromicro.com/en/Products/Current-Sensor-ICs.aspx , which would not affect the alternator

Comment: I like that idea, but the bulb has to go, would the current sensor work in line with the D+ terminal and the load resistor?

Comment: Why does the bulb have to go?

Comment: For many reasons, the intention is to monitor and control various functions of mechanical engines, sometimes they are in luxury / expensive vehicles which have digital dashboards and having a lamp wired up would be ugly and considered a bodge. There are also many other reasons where wiring a bulb etc is not acceptable, there has to be a single wire directly between the D+ terminal and my device.

Comment: You are detecting alternator field current that is amplified in the alternator to create a charge current by detecting the error voltage from an internal reference. Do you want to measure EXcitation current or charge current?  Either way, you need a 50mV to 75mV shunt at max current with an INA to amplify the voltage using a Kelvin-type shunt or even a length of flat wire.  What do you expect to measure?  Only the charge current can detect a bad 1 of 6 diodes?  THe excitation current is not linear with charge current and varies with RPM as well as faulty diodes

Comment: Use a simple optoisolator to sense the current for the bulb circuit (use two resistors, one replaces the bulb the other limits the opto input current. The output of the opto can drive your 3.3V MCU port directly.

Comment: Is this just for a Logic State, or real-time monitoring avg current or dynamic factors such as peak, ripple current indicating diode failure and partial loss of charge current of 3 phase.

Comment: I don't need to necessarily need to measure any current, my intention is just to replace the charge lamp with circuit monitored by a 3v3 MCU. There can be no visible light and all components have to fit on a PCB. I've tried to use a 4n32 onto exactly as you mention but it will not trigger no matter the resistor value.

Comment: There are probably better solutions, but the easiest I think would be the hall current sensor. It would work in line with the d+ terminal and resistor

Comment: @B.Baker You aren't showing the entire circuit and probably should do so. The alternator includes diodes and there is a "regulator" (not shown) that also sits on the D+ and then through to the rotor coil (not shown.) Showing these things would explain to some of us why you found that only a low-valued resistor would leave things working, for example. You also need to add an explanation about what happens with the rotor coil when the engine is running. Not everyone knows these circuits. And without these details, it is sometimes harder to provide a good answer.

Comment: @B.Baker So, for example, once folks here realize the diode situation inside the alternator, the 0.7 V you mentioned becomes easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Alternator schematic]

What happens at the indicator terminal is that there's a trio of diodes from the winding phases that provide the current for the field coil. When the alternator starts up, some current is needed through the field winding (on the rotor) for it to generate enough magnetic field to produce an output, so that's why you needed a low resistance to replace the bulb. Once the alternator is producing an output, the trio brings that terminal up to the same voltage as the battery, since the drops across the trio and main diodes are similar, so there's no potential across the bulb, and the trio is providing the field current.
 With the alternator not turning, the bulb (or bias resistor) current is still being dropped across the field winding, which is a few ohms so the voltage at the terminal is not zero.
 You could try putting a couple of diodes, (or a zener) in series with your 4k7 and another pulldown to ensure that the input is below the low state threshold on the MCU input.[image: alternator charge signal]

Other alternators have a regulator that switch the field internally based on the output of the windings under the residual magnetism of the rotor, these just have a transistor (usually a FET) that pull the indicator output down. These would function the same - they don't need the bulb or any other current source to aid starting up.

Answer (score 0):

The complexities inside the alternator do not come into play for your problem. This is a simple indicator. All you need is a replacement for the lamp (a resistor) to keep the alternator happy and the best way is to use an opto-isolator (which protects your MCU), what could be simpler.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDlzq6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The logic level Optoisolator I suggested ([TLP2361](https://toshiba.semicon-storage.com/info/docget.jsp?did=14229&prodName=TLP2361)) will work for a 3.3V MCU and provides push-pull drive for the DIO pin and can be readily Gnd isolated too.
You could still use the indicator lamp if you so desired.

Comment: This is what I originally thought, I did try it with a 4N32 but I could not get it to work.

Comment: @B.Baker Not all optos are the same. The 4N32 uses a bare-bones Darlington structure to receive from the LED emitter. The TLP2361 has conditioning and a proper output drive circuit to receive from its LED emitter. So a lot depends on the circuitry you applied to the 4N32's output side (which will not be anything like what Jack shows.) I can't say you did anything wrong or that the TLP2361 will perform better for you in this case. Just noting the difference to be dealt with.

Comment: @B.Baker I have a side-concern, though. The lamp provides a current-limiter function that helps protect the rotor coil regulator. For example, a direct application of the battery voltage without the lamp would likely wind up destroying it. Some care here is suggested, especially as it seems you are looking for a circuit that will apply reliably in a great many different scenarios; not all of them identical. The POTS phone system, for example, is actually any number of different switching systems with unique behaviors. Designing circuits to work with all of them was not an easy task, back then.

Comment: @jonk Not so, the circuit is obviously designed (by the automaker) so loss of an indicator lamp does NOT damage the alternator. Do design as you say would be asinine.

Comment: @jonk I suggested the TLP2361 for a reason, it is ideally suited for interface with a 3.3V MCU.

Comment: You may have misread what I wrote.

Comment: @jonk Which part of " For example, a direct application of the battery voltage without the lamp would likely wind up destroying it." did I misunderstand? You said without the lamp, so I assume you meant destroy the alternator? Was I wrong? If you meant the MCU, then your comment makes no sense at all.

Comment: Be careful with the tone, @Jack. It's coming across a bit narky. Jonk is a gentleman and gives excellent and well considered answers and comments.

Comment: @transistor. There was no 'tone' He was simply wrong and I pointed it out. I didn't misread (IMO) what he wrote and gave him the opportunity to correct it if he wanted.

Comment: That's fine, Jack. I'm just watching from the side and that's how it came across. It's one of the problems of the Internet age that we lose all the visual and vocal cues with text-only chat.

Comment: @JackCreasey I did *not* say that the alternator would be destroyed, nor had I wanted to imply it as a possibility. Please read back for the full context and see if you can read me more correctly. I apologize for my wording if it has caused you difficulties understanding me. But I think I was clear, just the same. (You might have chosen a less adversarial approach and simply asked me to clarify. So I suspect there was something else going on with you at the time that I don't understand, nor do I need to.)

Comment: @jonk Having re-read your comment multiple times I still do not see what you are saying would be destroyed by connecting the battery. Please explain what exactly might be destroyed?

Comment: @JackCreasey If you look back, you'll see me mentioning a "rotor coil regulator" in the immediately prior sentence. I didn't consider that difficult to read, which is why I asked you to look back. That set the context for the pronoun, "it," in the following sentence. In some circumstances and in some vehicles, these regulators can be destroyed without the current limiting effect of the light bulb. Been there, seen that, when someone made the mistake of bypassing the light by directly shorting the battery (+) terminal to the other side of a burned out light. (Phil, I see, has since added it.)

Comment: @jonk So you are saying it would destroy the regulator by leaving out the lamp?? Apart from your overly passive aggressive comment, I think you are absolutely wrong. And shorting out the lamp I would posit would never be viewed as a solution for even the most inexperienced DIY enthusiast. But let's just agree to disagree.

Comment: @JackCreasey I've seen it. But sure.